# In Debian 7 on Google Compute Engine, why don't any of my files appear when I type "ls" into the SSH terminal?

Tags: debian, vpn, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a VPN using the compute engine, but whenever I go to try and access a folder it says "No such file or directory" and when I do "ls", nothing comes up at all. I am very new to the Google Cloud platform and relatively new to the Linux platform as a whole.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your current directory there are no files, but if you do $ cd ..
you can see your main directory and try to make a file then cd, I think you must be in root to do that so .. $ sudo nano text.txt , then ls.